# is there a way to restrict/limit PATCH request with axios?

Tags: nuxt.js, comments, blogs, strapi

Using nuxt + strapi with its strapi-plugin-comments, I'd like to restrict logged users so they can only like/dislike comments once;

code here:

```js
methods: {
  async likeComment(commentId) {
    try {

      await this.$axios.$patch(
        `${this.$config.baseURL}/comments/post:${this.contentId}/comment/${commentId}/like`,
        {
          headers: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${this.$auth.$storage.getUniversal(
              'jwt'
            )}`,
          },
        }
      )
      this.$toast.success('Thank you for your input!').goAway(5000)
      window.location.reload(true)
    } catch (e) {
      this.$toast.error(e).goAway(5000)
    }
  },
}
```

Is there a way to restrict that PATCH request?

Comment: You can use local storage and keep track there of all posts the users voted on.

Comment: There is no way to restrict this on Strapi's side? The backend should be in charge of this kind of thing. Also, I really hope that you're not actually doing `window.location.reload(true)` in your app.

Comment: `window.location.reload()` will nuke your SPA here. You should get some HTTP response from your `PATCH` call. If you don't, you can probably make a `GET` again. Anyway, once you do have the updated content, you should mutate your state to make it reactive and get all the benefits of a modern SPA app (virtual DOM, reactivity etc...).

Comment: about window.location.reload(true), after doing a patch/post request this.$nuxt.refresh works so much better!

Comment: @Heimwerker yeah, it's better to only re-do the calls (Nuxt refresh) than nuking the whole SPA and hydrating it all back from scratch (window reload).